# Editing list properties using DataGridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, edit, bindinglist

Ok, I have my custom class:

```
    public class FileItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        int id=0;
        string value="";
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; Changed("Id"); }
        }
        public string Value
        {
            get { return value; }
            set { this.value = value; Changed("Value"); }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void Changed(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

 public BindingList<FileItem> FilesystemEntries = new BindingList<FileItem>();
```

And I have DatagridView1 with DataSource set to FilesystemEntries:

```
 binding.DataSource = FilesystemEntries;
```

Already  I can Add and remove rows - these chnages are reflected on collection.
However, Value and Id are not saved into bidning list when i change them in DataGridView, id is always 0 and value is "".

How can I make this work?
Do I need to implement some interface to FileItem to allow editing properties?

ReadOnly of DGV is set to false, same to all columns. Editing, Deleting and Changing are enabled.

Comment: Your example code works perfectly for me. Perhaps Zach's suggestion is the problem. Or is there something you haven't told us? Are you direct binding or using a binding source (my binding was direct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, it was not working because i set AutoGenerateColumns to false, and I added two columns in which i forgot to set DataSource property. Now its working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you clicked away from the editing cell to let the `DataGridView` know you are done editing the cell?  By default, the cell's value will not be pushed to the underlying object until you click away from it.